# Administrate facebook application via graph api

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was wondering if it is possible to change your site url or canvas url using the graph api. I have admin rights to my application and I can change it via the gui but I would prefer to be changing it via a curl.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example:

```
$properties = array(
    "callback_url" => '',
    "installable" => 1,
    "profile_tab_url" => "",
    "tab_default_name" => "",
    'tos_url' => '',
    'privacy_url' => ''
);

$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'YOUR_APP_ID','secret' = > '..', ...));

$facebook->api(array(
    'method'=>'admin_setAppProperties', 
    'properties'=>json_encode($properties))
);
```

Here is a list of the properties you can set: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/

There is also **admin.getAppProperties** more info you can find here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.getAppProperties/

Using [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Comment: Just to note that a graph API equivalent of this should be ready shortly, it'll be announced on the blog when this happens

Comment: so I tried this and I keep getting this error: Exception: 15: This method must be called with an app access_token. I then tried to get the access_token from the $_SESSION but that was failing too any suggestions?

Comment: app access token is simple your_app_id|your_secret_app_id so basicly you get a 2 numbers separated by | . You sould also check you application settings in the advanced options for "encrypted access token"

Comment: $app_settings = $facebook->api( array( 'method'=>'admin_getAppProperties',                                         'properties'=>json_encode($properties),                                            'access_token'=>$_SESSION['fb_APPID_access_token']) ); Shouldn't this work?

Comment: anyone know if the graph api is available yet?

Comment: Facebook has removed all traces of these functions from their documentation.  I have an apps that used to use admin.getAppProperties.  The method still works sort-of, but no longer returns the canvas namespace of the app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the old REST method admin.SetAppProperties
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.setAppProperties/

At the moment FB has not yet moved that method yet to the OpenGraph but you can still call REST methods via the Graph API (As shown in the console in the page above).

Even then you cannot change the secure_canvas and secure_tab url setting. FB is apparently working on make those settings as part of the API as far as I heard.

Answer (score 1):

You can now change app properties via Graph API.  You can make POST request, using the application id in the path, and use the app access token as the access token, and pass in key/value pairs as POST variables for properties you'd like to modify.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ has a list of the application properties that you can modify with the Graph API.